# Problems Simulating Interarrival Times

Tags: c++, math, distribution, simulation, sample

I'm attempting to simulate the occurrence of an event (a vehicle entering a tunnel), which as it turns out is a Poisson process.

I've broken the day up into 1 minute intervals, starting from 9am to 5pm.

For each 1 minute interval, I've computed/obtained the mean:

1. Number of vehicles that enter the tunnel during that period.
2. Time between each vehicle entering the tunnel (expected interarrival time)

For example for the minute 10:37-38 the mean is 5 vehicles with a mean inter-arrival time of 12seconds

To sample the 10:37-38 minute I do the following:

1. Sample a Poisson distribution with a mean of 5 to determine how many items will arrive, assign to X
2. Sample an exponential distribution of mean 1/12 X times to derive inter-arrival times y_0,y_1..._y_x
3. Sum the interarrival times and assign to K
4. If *K* is larger than 60seconds go to step 2
5. Accumulate various counters
6. Finally print statistics.

The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{

   double mean_num_itms = 5.0;
   double mean_inter_time = 12; //seconds
   double max_sec_in_period = 60; //seconds

   unsigned int rounds = 10000;

   std::random_device r;
   std::exponential_distribution<double> exponential(1.0 / mean_inter_time);
   std::poisson_distribution<double> poisson(mean_num_itms);

   double total_itms = 0;
   double total_inter_time = 0;

   for (std::size_t i = 0; i < rounds; ++i)
   {
      //Determine how many items will arrive in time period
      unsigned int num_itms = (unsigned int)(poisson(r));

      total_itms += num_itms;

      //Get the interarrival times for the 'num_itms'
      double last_arrival_time = 0;
      do
      {
         last_arrival_time = 0;
         for (unsigned int j = 0; j < num_itms; ++j)
         {
            double current_arrival_time = exponential(r);
            last_arrival_time += current_arrival_time ;
         }

      }
      //Reject any group of arrival times that exceed period span.
      while (last_arrival_time > max_sec_in_period);

      total_inter_time += last_arrival_time;

   }

   printf("Mean items per minute:   %8.3f\n"   ,total_itms / rounds);
   printf("Mean inter-arrival time: %8.3fsec\n",total_inter_time / total_itms);

   return 0;
}
```

The problem with the code above is:

1. The rejection part is very costly
2. The results for the mean inter-arrival time is incorrect:

   - Mean items per minute:      5.014
   - Mean inter-arrival time:    7.647sec

So my questions are as follows:

1. Is there a better more efficient technique to ensure that the total inter-arrival times never exceed the maximum number of seconds in the period?
2. Why is the mean inter-arrival time skewed down? for the example above I expect it to be roughly 12 - I think there's a bug in the code but can't seem to put my finger on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to simulate a [non-homogeneous Poisson process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inhomogeneous_Poisson_process) where lambda(t) is being defined in piece-wise segments to the nearest minute.

The correct way to do this is with "[thinning](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/nav.3800260304)".  Basically, find the maximum lambda(t) and generate pseudo-arrivals at times t<sub>1</sub>, t<sub>2</sub>, t<sub>3</sub>,... at rate lambda<sub>max</sub>. For each pseudo-arrival at time t<sub>i</sub>, accept it as a an actual arrival with probability lambda(t<sub>i</sub>) / lambda<sub>max</sub>. The result is a sequence of the times at which vehicles arrive at the tunnel.

Comment: that is exactly what I'm looking for! thanks for the paper it was very informative - never thought about the rate being "variable"

Comment: The link to the paper is dead. It's referring to "Simulation of nonhomogeneous poisson processes by thinning" by P. A. W Lewis and G. S. Shedler; doi: [10.1002/nav.3800260304](https://doi.org/10.1002/nav.3800260304)

Comment: @StanleyF. Many thanks for pointing that out, I've updated the link in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the way to go about simulating a Poisson process is to sample the interarrival time and construct arrival times from that -- sampling both the mean number per unit time and the interarrival time doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: I'm trying to simulate the i'th minute. So we sample the Poisson distribution to figure out how many events will occur during that particular sample for the i'th minute.  Then based on how many events will occur interarrival times are computed. Is that not right?