# How to simulate a Non-Homogenous Poisson Process?

Tags: python, statistics, simulation, distribution, poisson

I tried to simulate the NHPP in python. The function works but the numbers simulated don´t follow the NHPP.

The code is:

```
def nhpp(parametros,T,N):
    numeros=list()
    # the function of rate  λ(t) is a power law model, that is λ(t) = λ β **(−1) ,, , >0.
     
    funçao =lambda x:parametros[1] * parametros[0] * x ** (parametros[0] - 1)
  #calculate the maximum of the function in the interval (0,T)
    res=integrate.quad(funçao,0,T)
   # l represents the λ
    l=res[0]
    t=0
    cont=0
    contagem =list()
    listafinal=list()
    for i in range (1,N+1):
        u = numpy.random.uniform(0, 1)
      #t represents the exponential times generated
        t = t - (ln(u) / l)
       #fun represents the values of λ(t) for the t1,t2,t3...tN
        fun=parametros[1] * parametros[0] * t ** (parametros[0] - 1)
    # if u<λ(t)/λ we acept the time 
        if u<=fun/l:
            numeros.append(t)
     #cont represents the number of times (N(T)) that were acepted as NHPP
            cont = cont + 1
            contagem.append(cont)
    listafinal.append(numeros)
    listafinal.append(contagem)
    print(listafinal)
    return listafinal

x=nhpp([0.5,0.35],500,20000)
```

The output of this function is: `[[6.637092201160706, 12.739051189013342, 22.89616658744735, 161.12015416135688, 386.6019409119157, 424.7928356177192, 428.48931184149734, 733.1527508780554, 886.1376014091232, 1073.653026573429, 1133.4535462717483, 1787.4258499386765, 2077.7766357676205], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]]`

If I do the graphic of the points, the times between occurrences are not decreasing but they should because, when the B (parameter of power-law model) is < 1 (in this case is B=0.5), the times between occurrences decrease. Anyone can help simulate the NHPP in python correctly?

Note :In the power law process:case B<1 times inter failures decrease,case B=1 times inter failures constant,case B>1 times inter failures increase.

i want create someting like this :

[image: Plot of N(t) vs t]

In the picture the black line representes B=0,5 ,the blue line B=1, and the red line B=1,5.

Comment: Is N(t) supposed to be a cumulative total, or the count per unit time?

Comment: Wouldn't a higher rate of events correspond to more events per unit time, and thus to shorter inter-event times / higher density of points? Your plot and your note seem to have it backwards.

Answer (score 1):

### Update up-front

A common way to generate/simulate non-homogeneous Poisson processes is to use thinning. Candidate event times are generated at the maximal rate for the interval, and then thinned out by accepting a proportion of them based on the ratio of the instantaneous rate to the maximal rate. Unfortunately, this does not work if the maximal rate in the interval of interest is not finite, which can be the case when the rate function follows a [power law](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/apr/section4/apr452.htm) with `b < 1`. I've left the discussion of thinning below for people who find this post based on the question title.

NIST has an online manual which [describes a generating algorithm specific to the power law case](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/apr/section1/apr191.htm#Simulating%20NHPP%20Power%20Law%20Data). According to the link given above, in order to generate power law NHPP events with parameters `a=0.5` and `b=0.35` you should generate exponential random variates with rate `a`, add that to the prior time raised to the `b`<sup>th</sup> power, and then take the `b`<sup>th</sup> root of the sum to yield the next event time:

```python
import random

# params is a list containing rate a and power b.
# t is the amount of time to be simulated.
def nhpp(params, t):
    time = 0.0
    event = 0
    print("event time,event number")
    while True:
        # Generate b'th root of an exponential with rate "a",
        # and update the simulated time accordingly
        time = (time ** params[1] + random.expovariate(params[0])) ** (1/params[1])
        event += 1
        if time > t:
            break
        print(f"{time},{event}")


nhpp([0.5, 0.35], 10000)
```

which yields output such as:

```text
event time,event number
0.0027863666405411654,1
0.1663302577640816,2
0.3771684274752755,3
36.54675259117693,4
76.353564909201,5
260.547640677633,6
292.0182519323185,7
406.34546142065693,8
5342.127722590645,9
5472.997406321742,10
5844.439757675029,11
8521.086105482522,12
```

### How to simulate NHPP in python using thinning

The thinning technique's principles are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19568982/2166798). The following is a heavily annotated sample implementation of how to do it in Python:

```python
import math
import random

# A frequency that cycles every 20 time units, in radians
OMEGA = 0.05 * 2 * math.pi

# A sinusoidal time-varying rate, truncated at zero
rate_f = lambda t: max(0, 4 - (16 * math.cos(OMEGA * t)))

# The rate function above gives a maximum instantaneous arrival rate
# of 20 events per time unit, i.e., 4 - (16 * -1) when cos == -1
lambda_max = 20.0

# The following should generate 5 cycles of non-zero
# event epochs between time 0 and time 100
t = 0.0
print("time of event")
while True:
    # generate Poisson candidate event times using
    # exponentially distributed inter-event delays
    # at the maximal rate
    t += random.expovariate(lambda_max)
    # stop if we're past time 100
    if t > 100.0:
        break
    # (rate_f(t) / lambda_max) is the probability we
    # should accept a candidate at time t
    if random.random() <= rate_f(t) / lambda_max:
        # Accept and print this as an actual event if
        # a U(0,1) is below the threshold probability
        print(t)
```

This sample program generates results as described in the comments of the code.

[image: Event frequencies for 100 time units showing 5 cycles.]

Comment: I have eddited and  commented my code to explain what i did, and i added a picture that show what i wanna to creat. Please, Mister @pjs can you check this ? thank you so much.

Comment: @RubenMartins Okay, so `funçao` is your rate function if I have understood your comments correctly.  Are you aware that the rate is infinity at t = 0 for all 0 <  B < 1? So what does that mean to you from a modeling perspective, because to me it looks like you don't have a reasonable rate function.

Comment: @RubenMartins For B > 1, the maximum rate for thinning would be `funçao(T)`. I'm still wondering why you've tried setting it to the integral of funçao.

Comment: @RubenMartins You're still going to get screwed up results by using the same `u` for generating the exponential inter-event times and for deciding upon acceptance/rejection.

Comment: yes , my rate function is extacly this, wich is a  reliability  model very used to model failure times that follows NHPP . you can reab about this model in: https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/apr/section4/apr452.htm.

Comment: i know that when b<1 the max of the function is 9999999...So to the find the max of the function in Tmax i do the integral of function (0,tmax)

Comment: @jps I m going generating again the exponential inter-event times again , correctly and after im going verficy the results

Comment: Your NIST link actually gives a simple algorithm specific to power law data. If you click through the right sequence of links, you get to https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/apr/section1/apr191.htm#Simulating%20NHPP%20Power%20Law%20Data.  By the way, putting the link to the handbook in your question would be highly relevant.

Comment: i´m gonna triiyng to do this algorithm. thank you so much for the help

Comment: i have found the correct R code to simulate this process , you can help me to convert the r code to python code? thank you.

Comment: @RubenMartins I've already given python code at the top of my answer.

Comment: yes i know, but this code don´t produces the results that i expected. I found a R code that produces the results that i want. But ,i don´t have kownlage about R language, plese you can check the code in : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73113882/how-to-simulate-the-nhpp-in-python

Comment: @RubenMartins 1) I'm not an R user. 2) What makes you so sure the R code is correct, given that the python code above is a straight translation of the algorithm in the handbook you linked as the definitive source?

Comment: i made a mistake, i changed the "a" parameter with the "b" parameter and know  i have the results that i expect. the algorithm and the code are absolotley right. thank you very much and sorry for my mistake .